# Change Variable Value using a function with select values

Tags: javascript, function, variables, select

How can I change the value of a variable which is outside a function. I want the variable "yr" in my code to be updated with a value from select form by the function update variable.

I looking to update the variable "yr", with the value from the drop down list in my html below. Then I want to use the value of "yr" in another variable called chart4. I have updated the code below.

```js
var yr = "2017";

function updatevariable(data) { 
  yr = data;
        console.log(yr);
};

var chart4 = {
  "columns": [
    {
      "dimension": "dx",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "fbfJHSPpUQD" 
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
         "dimension": "pe",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": yr 
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "filters": [
    {
      "dimension": "ou",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "fdc6uOvgoji"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "el": "chart4"
};
```

```html
<select id="year" name="year" onchange="updatevariable(this.value)">
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's wong with what you already have?

Comment: The code you have should work

Comment: When I console log the variable yr outside the function i am getting the value 2017 at page load/refresh. but after when i select a different option there after the value of yr doesn't seem to change.

Comment: Hey Is my whole code: Intend to user the value of year in the variable chart3.

Comment: Is the question you are asking why doesn't it keep the value after the page is reloaded/refreshed?

Comment: It all works for me, what's wrong with it?

Comment: I have updated the code above, to show the other part where i want to use the value stored in the variable "yr". The issue is even when i select a different year on the drop down, the chart4 does not change to display data fro that year.

Answer (score 0):

The function you written is correct one to change the value of the variable outside the function.
And a simple demo to understand that,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var yr = "2017";
        function updatevariable(data) { 
                yr = data;
        };
        function print(){
            alert(yr);
            console.log(yr);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="year" name="year" onchange="updatevariable(this.value)">
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="print()">Updated date</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding an assignment to the yr inside char4 every time the drop down menu is changed.

Hope this will help!

```
var yr = "2017";

function updatevariable(data) { 
        yr = data;
        chart4.rows[0].items[0].id = yr;
        console.log(chart4.rows[0].items[0].id);
};

var chart4 = {
  "columns": [
    {
      "dimension": "dx",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "fbfJHSPpUQD" 
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "rows": [
    {
         "dimension": "pe",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": yr 
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "filters": [
    {
      "dimension": "ou",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "fdc6uOvgoji"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "el": "chart4"
};
```